# Mysql suddenly restarts. Or how to make connection forever

Tags: mysql

Any idea what reason can be when mysql server disconnects all connected clients? It seems as mysql self-restarting

> 2018-01-23T17:52:49.321637Z 0 [Note] Giving 30 client threads a chance
>   to die gracefully 2018-01-23T17:52:49.353796Z 0 [Note] Shutting down
>   slave threads 2018-01-23T17:52:51.599556Z 0 [Note] Forcefully
>   disconnecting 11 remaining clients 2018-01-23T17:52:51.599586Z 0
>   [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8592332  user:
>   'root'
>
> 2018-01-23T17:52:51.599611Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing
>   close of thread 13362  user: 'root'

That happens every 2-4 days.
I have many processes that connect to mysql on launching and must serve forever. And yes that processes access to mysql all the time, so it's not timeout disconnect

Comment: Why not research over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please answer these few questions. Q1) Rotating HD  nnn of Spindles,  nnn TB/GB/MB and  nnn TB/GB/MB Free Space  
Q2) SSD  nnn TB/GB and  nnn TB/GB/MB Free Space of SSD
Q3) RAM  nnn TB/GB/MB on your Host server, indicate DEDICATED or SHARED w other apps?
 
Post to via dropbox, pastebin or similar service current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
we can get by if you STOP here, for more detailed analysis, continue please
C) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for analysis and suggestions will be provided.